# Remote port forwarding using jsch?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using the library jsch to make ssh connection. I am useing following code;

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", port);
```

But how to put some specific option while I am creating the connection? Actually I want to replicate;

**ssh -R abc:8080:localhost80 mysite.com**

- This command using jsch.

Is it possible using jsch? Or I should use some other library.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were u able to do that ? I am in similar problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it more options than port forwarding that you need?

Port forwarding (as in `-R`) is possible with JSch - [example here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingR.java.html).

If the objective is emulating the OpenSSH command line options, this would be  tougher.  To the best of my knowledge, all the various SSH libraries for Java, JSch included, focus on providing connectivity for applications that need SSH support.  That sounds like it would need a small project in command line parsing.